# Angular HttpClient , Param with name 'query' failed to set

Tags: angular

I have got a `params` variable in Angular service which is of type `HttpParams`.

When I do

```
params.set('sortby', sortby.toString());
```

or

```
params.set('top', top.toString());
```

both of this are working and getting added to `params` variable and passing on to the API.

However the issue is when I have a route param defined as `'query'` in the API. I failed to understand why my code,

```
params.set('query', query.toString());
```

not working at all. It just don't get added to the params list. I assume it is something to do with the name `'query'`. Updating API is not a choice at this moment.

Is there a way I could make `'query'` work?

API Call :

[image]

Try updating directly to the request from chrome console. Even then I could not find the query param.

[image]

EDIT : newParams()

That is returning the HttpParams with a correct codec

```
protected newParams(): HttpParams {
    return new HttpParams({
      encoder: PARAMETER_CODEC
    });
  }
```

And Encoder is ,

```
class ParameterCodec implements HttpParameterCodec {
  encodeKey(key: string): string {
    return encodeURIComponent(key);
  }

  encodeValue(value: string): string {
    return encodeURIComponent(value);
  }

  decodeKey(key: string): string {
    return decodeURIComponent(key);
  }

  decodeValue(value: string): string {
    return decodeURIComponent(value);
  }
}
const PARAMETER_CODEC = new ParameterCodec();
```

Comment: Can you please add your generated service link? And also add if there is error/warning messages or screenshots...

Comment: what is query.toString()?

Comment: and also are you trying ```params = params.set('query', "alo");``` not just  ```params.set('query', "alo");``` ?

Comment: doing `let params = new HttpParams().set('query', 'myname')` works fine for me

Comment: are you sure `params.query` actually exists? Try setting the query param with some random string, and see if that works

Comment: Yes it does, I confirmed it

Comment: @TBA so it works with a random string? or params.query exists :)?

Comment: I meant the params.query I tried setting with different value even then it did not show up. Was just mentioning the value was existing  and it was not null

Comment: I even tried setting it from the console. It did not give me any error however it failed to add to the params array. I updated the screenshot

Comment: Try printing `params.toString()` or open `HttpRequest.params.updates`, query should be there. What is the value you are setting?

Comment: if I change to  if (params.query != null) __params = __params.set('query2', params.query.toString()); It just adds the value with query2

Comment: Only problem is query ?

Comment: @Ludevik if I expand it I don't see the query  param at all, if I rename that param to query2 its available

Comment: @TBA are you running an old version of angular by any chance? and better yet, what is `this.newParams()`?

Comment: @TBA, please try to explain more about the issue in original question, also make sure to share some code snippet from what ever you have tried.

Comment: I added as much as I could as screenshots and updated few more code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are wondering why no parameters get passed, there is a key hint in the referenced **[HttpParams](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpParams)** docs

> This class is immutable - all mutation operations return a new
>   instance.

Basically you should be able to send params/query by chaining like this to have multiple params:

```
    const params = new HttpParams()
        .set('query', 'value here')
        .set('another_param', 'value_here')
        .set('sortby', sortby.toString());

return this.httpClient.get('my url', { params })
```

If you want to append `HttpParams` conditionally, use a variation of this instead, Ex:

```
let params = new HttpParams();
if ( limit ) {
  params = params.set('limit', String(limit));
}
params = params.set('search', keyword);
```

Comment: @nircraft He can try chaining the set for the query param, the result can tell us more.

Comment: Thanks Any Ways but this won't let me solve my issue because I gotta check for null

Comment: @TBA, please try to explain more about the issue in original  question, also make sure to share some code snippet from what ever you have tried. `params = new Params()` doesn't work. had it been your code snippet not some screenshot you would have got the answer quicker.